SIM7000E fails to run HTTPS request
first of all, I have searched the internet for hours and tried a lot of advices, but I still do not know, how to run the HTTPS request. Modem boud rate is 9600, SIM card is registered with the operator, GPRS gets attached automatically.
Here is a list of AT commends used:
23:44:06.945 -> AT+CMEE=2
23:44:06.945 -> OK
23:44:11.455 -> AT+CSTT="internet.t-mobile.cz","",""
23:44:11.455 -> OK
23:44:15.914 -> AT+CIICR
23:44:17.670 -> OK
23:44:19.519 -> AT+CNACT=1, "internet.t-mobile.cz"
23:44:19.572 -> OK
23:44:19.572 -> 
23:44:19.572 -> +APP PDP: ACTIVE
23:44:23.681 -> AT+CSSLCFG="ignorertctime",1,1
23:44:23.728 -> OK
23:44:30.449 -> AT+CSSLCFG="sslversion",1,3
23:44:30.502 -> OK
23:44:35.161 -> AT+SHSSL=1,""
23:44:35.161 -> OK
23:44:38.871 -> AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024
23:44:38.871 -> +CME ERROR: operation not allowed
23:44:44.181 -> AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",64
23:44:44.181 -> OK
23:44:48.792 -> AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350
23:44:48.845 -> OK
23:44:52.874 -> AT+SHCONF="URL", "https://httpbin.org"
23:44:52.920 -> OK
23:44:58.170 -> AT+SHCONN
23:45:23.538 -> +CME ERROR: operation not allowed

23:51:02.936 -> AT+CGMR
23:51:02.936 -> Revision:1529B01SIM7000E
23:51:02.936 -> 
23:51:02.936 -> OK

I used a guide from this site: https://gist.github.com/baconcheese113/1f0264727fce3fa51a5bb06fa031aed2
First trouble is with the BODYLEN parameter and SHCONN takes a lot of time before failure.
Thanks for help.
